# Control structure scope and casting interface to concrete object

Tags: c#, if-statement, casting, scope, coding-efficiency

I was trying to write this code a bit more proper by reducing repeated code.

```
private void makeNewItem(IMovingObject item)
{
    if (item is Car)
    {
        Car auto = (Car)item;
        autos.Add(auto);
        listBoxBedrijf.Items.Add(auto);
        auto.NieuweLocatieEvent += updateLocatie;
    }
    else if (item is Truck)
    {
        Truck bestel = (Truck)item;
        bestelwagens.Add(bestel);
        listBoxBedrijf.Items.Add(bestel);
        bestel.NieuweLocatieEvent += updateLocatie;
    }
    else
    {
        Person persoon = (Person)item;
        personeelsleden.Add(persoon);
        listBoxBedrijf.Items.Add(persoon);
        persoon.NieuweLocatieEvent += updateLocatie;
    }
}
```

To something like this:

```
private void makeNewItem(IMovingObject item)
{
    if (item is Car)
    {
        Car itemConverted = (Car)item;
        autos.Add(itemConverted);

    }
    else if (item is Truck)
    {
        Truck itemConverted = (Truck)item;
        bestelwagens.Add(itemConverted);
    }
    else
    {
        Person itemConverted = (Person)item;
        personeelsleden.Add(itemConverted);
    }

    listBoxBedrijf.Items.Add(itemConverted);
    itemConverted.NieuweLocatieEvent += updateLocatie;
}
```

But the problem is that the `itemConverted` is not available outside of the control structure scope, even if I change the last `else if` to `else`, so the variable would always exist.

When I create a `Object itemConverted = null;` in the beginning, the last code isn't aware of the methods that the concrete objects have (due to the shared interface).

I'd appreciate some advice on how to do this properly. I have not so much experience with object casting.

This is the interface code as requested:

```
public interface IMovingObject
{
    Locatie Locatie { get; set; }

    string locatieToString();

    string TrackId { get; set; }

    void WaarschuwDoel();
}
```

Comment: Why not just add `IMovingObject `? can you provide your interface definition?

Comment: @HesamFaridmehr Because the interface is very slim. Most of the functionality is in the base class of the vehicles and the Person class. Also I can't use the event delegate if only using the interface

Comment: you can use event delegate in interfaces. Please provide your interface code

Comment: @HesamFaridmehr Added it as requested

Comment: so just add `event NieuweLocatieEventHandler NieuweLocatie;` to your interface

Comment: @HesamFaridmehr I didn't know that worked. But still it's only partially an improvement, because there's still `listBoxBedrijf.Items.Add(itemConverted);`. So am I right to assume that there's is no one way to write it better with all my code in its current state?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172913/discussion-between-hesam-faridmehr-and-earthmind).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use an abstract class instead of an interface. The abstract class (MovingObject) would include your interface methods and the property NieuweLocatieEvent. listBoxBedrijf would accept MovingObject items.

```
private void makeNewItem(MovingObject item)
{
  if (item is Car)
  {
    autos.Add((Car)item);
  }
  else if (item is Truck)
  {
    bestelwagens.Add((Truck)item);
  }
  else
  {
    personeelsleden.Add((Person)item);
  }
  listBoxBedrijf.Items.Add(item);
  //Assuming NieuweLocatieEvent is public
  item.NieuweLocatieEvent += updateLocatie;
}
```

If that is not possible, then you would have to include the line itemConverted.NieuweLocatieEvent in each if clause and modify listBoxBedrijf so it accepts IMovingObject.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to use an interface somewhere in the code as it's a school assignment. If I create an interface just for one abstract class, that would take away the point of the interface